# Multi-Client Server request Handler

Tags: java, sockets, request, client, serversocket

I need to implement a Server in java that accepts connections from clients (no limit) then the clients make requests to the server and the server should respond to the request, but just to the client who made the request. I dont know how to start with this... 
I can make it work  1 to 1 connection, and I know How to make a multi-client chat in which the server respond to everyone, but how can I, from the server, select the client to respond, just to that which made the request??

```
package negocio;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
//import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Servidor {
    private ServerSocket servidor;
    private Socket cliente;
    private OutputStream os;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private InputStream is;
    private DataInputStream leerS;
    private DataOutputStream escribirS;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;


    public Servidor(){
        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(5000);
            System.out.println("creador serv");
            cliente = new Socket();
            cliente = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println("cliente conec");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String recibirString(){
        String mens = ""; 
        try {
             leerS = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
             mens =  "Mensaje del cliente: "+leerS.readUTF();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
        return mens;
    }


    public Object recibirObjeto(){
     System.out.println("Recibiendo");
       try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
        return ois.readObject();
       } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("llego nullo");
        return null;
       }
     }

    public void enviarObjeto(Object obj){
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Any decent tutorial on network client-server programming will show you. Did you do any research?  Hint: Your `accept` call must be inside an infinite loop and you must launch a separate thread to handle each client connection.

Comment: @JimGarrison's hint is great, but I would avoid launching a thread for each new connection (it's a security risk and you will learn less using this technique). Look into `epoll`, `kqueue` (system dependent), or (if this is a study/school project) the `select` system calls and non-blocking sockets.

Comment: Regardless of how you acquire connections, you must have a separate thread actually handle the client request.  If you handle the request on the main loop you will be unable to handle more than one request at a time.  If you're worried about DOS attacks you can limit the number of threads available and queue requests (with a limited queue depth) if all threads are active.